Postgres server killed by OOM during pg_restore
I'm running Postgres 16.3 in a container with a 1 GB memory limit. When I run pg_restore with a dump file that's about 1 GB, the server will be killed by OOM and I'm guessing that this is from the auto-vacuum using too much memory.
Here's the logs from one time it happened:
2024-09-19 21:01:58.441 UTC [215] LOG:  checkpoint starting: wal 
2024-09-19 21:02:14.444 UTC [215] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 4643 buffers (28.3%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 33 recycled; write=15.710 s, sync=0.218 s, total=16.003 s; sync files=39, longest=0.077 s, average=0.006 s; distance=537593 kB, estimate=545819 kB; lsn=1D/1138CA88, redo lsn=1C/F303F258
2024-09-19 21:02:15.706 UTC [215] LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (17 seconds apart)
2024-09-19 21:02:15.706 UTC [215] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
2024-09-19 21:02:15.707 UTC [215] LOG:  checkpoint starting: wal 
2024-09-19 21:02:25.152 UTC [1] LOG:  server process (PID 234) was terminated by signal 9: Killed 
2024-09-19 21:02:25.152 UTC [1] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: COPY public.auth_user (id, password, last_login, is_superuser, username, first_name, last_name, email, is_staff, is_active, date_joined) FROM stdin;

2024-09-19 21:02:25.152 UTC [1] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2024-09-19 21:02:25.210 UTC [1] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2024-09-19 21:02:25.236 UTC [241] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2024-09-19 21:02:14 UTC
2024-09-19 21:02:25.797 UTC [241] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress 
2024-09-19 21:02:25.801 UTC [241] LOG:  redo starts at 1C/F303F258
2024-09-19 21:02:34.673 UTC [241] LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1C/D5C24000 in WAL segment 000000010000001D00000021, LSN 1D/21C24000, offset 12730368
2024-09-19 21:02:34.673 UTC [241] LOG:  redo done at 1D/21C23FA0 system usage: CPU: user: 5.42 s, system: 3.34 s, elapsed: 8.87 s
2024-09-19 21:02:35.248 UTC [242] LOG:  checkpoint starting: end-of-recovery immediate wait 
2024-09-19 21:02:35.687 UTC [242] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 15986 buffers (97.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 46 recycled; write=0.162 s, sync=0.218 s, total=0.441 s; sync files=45, longest=0.210 s, average=0.005 s; distance=765843 kB, estimate=765843 kB; lsn=1D/21C24048, redo lsn=1D/21C24048
2024-09-19 21:02:35.697 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

Is that what appears to be causing the issue? Is there a way to disable or limit the auto-vacuum during a restore so it will be able to finish without issue?

Maybe try putting your failing restore  into several batches?

Why would you think it is autovacuum?

The memory usage shoots up after the restore has been running for a bit and the logs indicate that auto-vacuum is happening, so that's why I believe it's the case. Could also be ANALYZE that's causing the problem.

I tried the same restore with the new 17 release and the issue no longer happens. The peak memory usage is around 500 MB, so it appears the improvements related to that release have resolved the issue.
